# I don't understand the structure of this

Tags: sentence-structure

> There is not such a cradle of democracy upon the earth **as** the Free Public Library, this republic of letters, where neither rank, office, nor wealth receives the slightest consideration.

This is a quote by Andrew Carnegie. But I don't understand the structure of this sentence, especially *as*.

Answer (score 1):

Remembering an idiomatic phrase such as *There is no such thing as a free lunch* could help you parse the *such ... as* structure (such as the one in your example).

As for your sentence, I parse it like this:

> There is not such (a cradle of democracy upon the earth) as the Free Public Library, this republic of letters, (where neither rank, office, nor wealth receives the slightest consideration).

Also note that the *this republic of letters* part refers to *the Free Public Library*. (But I suspect that you might already know this.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Side note: the "free lunch" phrase usually (but not always) has *ain't* rather than *is*, hence *TANSTAAFL*.

Comment: So it means, "There is nothing like a free public library when it comes to bringing about democracy?"

Comment: Basically, yes.